# Why is WHERE condition ignored in LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm having a problem limiting the left result set with a WHERE clause, even when I put the same condition in the subquery that forms the right result set.  Here's an example:

```
SELECT shareItems.*, likes FROM shareItems LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT users_X_shareItems.itemID, COUNT(users_X_shareItems.userID) AS 'likes'
    FROM users_X_shareItems, shareItems WHERE shareItems.itemType = 2 AND
    users_X_shareItems.liked = 1
    GROUP BY users_X_shareItems.itemID) AS likeTable
ON shareItems.itemID = likeTable.itemID AND shareItems.itemType = 2
```

Despite my specifying shareItems.itemType = 2 in both queries, it's ignored.  Anybody know why?  Thanks.

Comment: Note the slight changes to the title - one presumes that it *is* a bug/issue with SQL, while the other presents a problem and asks for clarification. A minor point, but try to avoid "begging bugs".

Comment: There is no WHERE clause in your outer query. If you want predicates applied in a WHERE clause, you need to add a WHERE clause. BTW... I think your counts are inflated; in the inline view, you're doing a GROUP BY on item_id, but you're joining to all rows from the shareItems table that are `itemType=2`; we'd expect to see a join predicate that matches that `itemID` to `shareItems.itemID`. It just looks like it's missing to me; likely something I don't understand about your schema or what resultset you are wanting to return.

Comment: Spencer, your observation is correct, but this is just part of a three-way query.  The full query does relate the itemIDs in the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to limit the left side of your LEFT JOIN, you need to put the condition as WHERE, not on the JOIN (that will only limit the right side):

```
 ON shareItems.itemID = likeTable.itemID
 WHERE shareItems.itemType = 2
```

Comment: +1 Exactly. There is no WHERE clause on the outer query, there are no "WHERE conditions" on the outer query. Predicates evaluated in the ON clause of an outer join are not predicates in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I had tried putting a WHERE clause in the initial SELECT at the top, but that was rejected.  So I thought the ON replaced WHERE and could contain the additional conditions.

Answer (score 1):

They are not ignored, they are being applied BEFORE the records from the inner side of the join which have no match in the outer table have been added to the result set.
because the predicate is part of the join, it is applied as part of the join, then after that happens, all records form the inner side that have no match are added back in.. Since there is no match, the predicate on the outer side cannot (by definition of OUTRER it ***cannot***) be applied then. 
All such records, because there is no match in the outer table, will of course have null values in any attributes which should have come from that table anyway, so the predicate can't be applied at that point anyway.

Move the predicate condition to a WHERE clause, then it will be applied after the outer join, and will do what you want.